# How do I swap out the default scheduler for testing in RxJs5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, rxjs5

I have an AngularJS service that uses `Rx.Observable.Interval` in RxJs version 5 to poll an API every 30 seconds and I would like to write a unit test for it using an `VirtualTimeScheduler`.

However, the service does not specify a scheduler and I'd prefer not to change the original code (which is far more complex than the example below) to inject a default scheduler:

```
function checkStatus(){
   // The scheduler could be provided as a 2nd arg to interval
   return Rx.Observable.interval(1000*30).switchMap(()=> {
      return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(
         StatusApiService.get()
      )
   })
}
```

Is there an easy way I can tell RxJs to use a different scheduler for the `interval` factory in the unit test, without changing the original code to make the scheduler configurable?

```
const scheduler = new Rx.VirtualTimeScheduler();
const subscriber = jasmine.createSpy('subscriber');
// TODO: swap out scheduler with VirtualTimeScheduler
checkStatus().subscribe(subscriber)
scheduler.flush();  // fake 10 minutes of time passing
expect(StatusApiService.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(20);
```

Comment: This isn't going to be exactly what you want, but it might give you some ideas: https://github.com/tchock/RxJS-TestScheduler-Injector